# Cant find exe file after project release build

Tags: exe

I have built a windows form app. (c#) and have added an app.exe file in bin/Debug/app.exe to run when a play button is pressed on the initial (first) form.

When debugging/running in visual studio 2010 the thing works perfectly, with no issues... but when I build the "Release" project and execute using the generated Main.exe in the Release folder, or running in VS I've just noticed after Release build, I receive a message when the play button is clicked saying "The system cannot find the specified".

I also notice that after building the Release version, in the solution explorer my nested folders now have a bin/Debug inside the bin/Debug, so: bin/Degub/app.exe | /bin/Debug/app.exe, its repeated... is this correct?

Is it possible to achieve this in a Release build?

The code I am using to run app.exe on play button click is;

```
Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "app.exe";
            p.Start();
```

Your help will be very much appreciated, thank you. :)

Comment: I think you just need to add the app to the `bin/Release/` folder so you can find it when running in release mode.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, that has worked. But is there a way to wrap everything (including the app.exe) neatly into one exe file? I just want one file that the user can click/open, instead of them having to install, like with the ClickOnce option.

Comment: I don't think there is a very easy way outside of pulling all the code out of app.exe and putting it into your other project so they all form 1 exe.  You could also change it to a DLL, but then you would still have to distribute both the exe and the DLL.

Comment: OK, thanks for your help. Munch appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's where you saved it. To find it right click source explorer and click 'open with file explorer' then head to bin then go to where you saved it in the combo box, like release or debug. Or if you made a specialized name then go to name/debug or name/release.